# How to do a for with fades in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have this div:

```
<div id="blink">blink</div>
```

And I want do blink it three times. [This ugly code does that](http://jsfiddle.net/22bpkhtf/):

```
var t = animationTime = 600;

$("#blink").fadeOut(t).fadeIn(t).fadeOut(t).fadeIn(t).fadeOut(t).fadeIn(t);
```

---

But what if I want it to blink ten times?

How can I loop those fades?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animation on the same element gets added to a queue, so just add them in a loop! @:)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){ 
    $("#blink").fadeOut(t).fadeIn(t);
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/22bpkhtf/2/

Comment: there we go, thats better :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `complete` callback

```js
var t = tempoAnimacao = 600;
var numTimes = 10;

$("#blink").fadeOut(t).fadeIn(t, callback);

function callback() {
  numTimes--;
  if (numTimes) {
    $("#blink").fadeOut(t).fadeIn(t, callback);
  }
}
```

```css
#blink {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blink">blink</div>
```

Comment: callbacks are not needed at all for fades as they get queued for that element.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, I do remember something along those lines. But why is it not working? http://jsfiddle.net/22bpkhtf/1/

Comment: Because of my typos... just adding a JSfiddle :) http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/22bpkhtf/2/